# DB2 ERROR [07004] SQL0313N

Tags: c#, sql, db2

I am a newbie in DB2 world and am using:
- DB2 Data Provider for .NET (IBM.Data.DB2.dll version 9.7.4.4)
- C# VS2010 with .NET Framework 4.0

I have problem with query that uses parameter.
My code snippet:

> ```
> DB2Command cmd = new DB2Command();
> cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CUSTOMERS t0 WHERE (t0.\"CITY\" < :p0)";
> cmd.Connection = Db2Connection;
> DB2Parameter param = cmd.CreateParameter();
> param.DB2Type = DB2Type.VarChar;
> param.ParameterName = ":p0";
> param.Value = "Seattle";
> var p = cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
> var execResult = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
> ```

I get following error on cmd.ExecuteScalar():

> The number of variables in the EXECUTE statement, the number of
>   variables in the OPEN statement, or the number of arguments in an OPEN
>   statement for a parameterized cursor is not equal to the number of
>   values required. SQLSTATE=07004

Please help how to fix the problem. Thank you in advance.

Additional information:
1. I just tried to use IBM Data Studio to verify the DB2 command using query editor. It doesn't recognize the prefix "@" for parameter. So I use oracle-liked prefix ":" for it. It works. But my C# code still raises the error [07004] SQL0313N
2. If I don't use any prefix for parameter on my C# code, I get ERROR [42703] [IBM][DB2/NT64] SQL0206N  \"P0\" is not valid in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I find out 2 ways to fix the problem.

1. Using unnamed parameter "?" instead of parameter name ":p0".

   ```
   DB2Command cmd = new DB2Command();  
   cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CUSTOMERS t0 WHERE (t0.\"CITY\" < ?)";  
   cmd.Connection = Db2Connection;  
   DB2Parameter param = cmd.CreateParameter();  
   param.DB2Type = DB2Type.VarChar;  
   param.ParameterName = "param1";  
   param.Value = "Seattle";  
   var p = cmd.Parameters.Add(param);  
   var execResult = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
   ```
2. Activate **HostVarParameters** property of class DB2ConnectionStringBuilder and the original code remains unchanged (keeping using named parameters).

My 2 cents,
Mag

Comment: can you provide more details on item # 2 ?

Comment: @EricSchneider unfortunately no, because it is an old thread (2014!) and I don´t work on this case anymore.